# Error: Code=InvalidContentLink when deploying to Azure

Tags: installation, paas, arm-template

I am trying to set-up Sitecore XP 9.2 standalone in Azure PAAS using `Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.3.0 rev. 190410` following the link at https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--deploying-a-new-sitecore-environment-to-the-microsoft-azure-app-service.html

The script fails  validation with the following log:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 3:57:05 PM - Error: Code=InvalidContentLink; Message=Unable to download
deployment content from
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/Sitecore
9.2.0/XPSingle/azuredeploy.json/azuredeploy.json'. The tracking Id is '9b6559dc-0199-4200-bff1-ca8dd4b0bd54'. Please
see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.
At D:\Personal\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.3.0 rev. 190410\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:115 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

I do understand that the link getting logged is not able to open in the browser. 
It should have been `"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/Sitecore%209.2.0/XPSingle/azuredeploy.json"`

But I tried both below options but the output is the same.

1. $SCTemplates=
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/Sitecore%209.2.0/XPSingle/azuredeploy.json"
2. $SCTemplates=
       "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/Sitecore
       9.2.0/XPSingle/azuredeploy.json"

Any input will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file 'Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1', at line 115, replace `($ArmTemplateUrl -replace ' ', '%20')` by the value copied from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I been facing the issue with Raw Parameter, PFA screen shot,

any help will be appreciated

```
ExtendedProperties : {}

Deployment Started...
VERBOSE: Setting ARM template parameters...
Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.
At D:\scXPscaled\sitecore-install-powershell.ps1:27 char:1
+ Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment -Verbose -Name $DeploymentId -Location  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment
```

Comment: This seems to be a new question. Please ask it as a new question. It will help to get a better response from the community.